# how to setup the kaa platform develop environment?

Tags: kaa

We download the Kaa platform source code from git.
We can build it successfully under linux OS.
And we also try to import it by Eclipse.
But, it will show a lot of error after import Kaa project into Eclipse.
Does the develop environment need under linux and need to use other develop tool??
Have anyone can share the guide instruction to help setup the Kaa platform develop environment??
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

We try to use IntelliJ IDEA (community version) to import all source from git.
And then, use the "Generates Sources and Updates Folders" function of Maven to generate some source that it need.
After generating the source that lack before and the project can be built successfully.
Finally, we use the package command to generate the rpm and deb file.
Above all operation is on Linux OS.

The Eclipse should also support above operation, but it should be more setting need to set. And it seems more convenient by IntelliJ IDEA.